# Find Sum of list with condition

Tags: python

I am stuck at a problem.

I have a List L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

I want to find the sum of elements in lists such that, if the sum exceeds's 25. I want to get the previous sum.

for eg. 1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28, 28>25. Therefore i want a final variable sum as 21.

i am doing it using **for-if combination**, but i don't want to use **if** . Is there a better way of doing this? below is my code.

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
summ = 0

for val in L:
    summ+= val
    if summ > 25:
        summ-=val
```

Comment: Is that a contrived homework requirement or is there a good reason not to use `if`?

Answer (score 3):

I think what bothers you is the `summ-=val` part, not the *if*. And there is a one line solution with `reduce`.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y if x + y <= 25 else x, L)
21
```

---

1. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
i = 0
s = 0
while i < len(L) and s + L[i] < 25:
    s += L[i]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about integrating the condition into the mathematical expression:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
summ = 0

for val in L:
    summ = summ+val*(summ+val <= 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, take the cumulative sum on a series consisting of the numbers in the list.  Assign the value `NaN` to any any cumulative sum over `max_value`.  Fill forward the result and convert back to a list of integers.

```
import pandas as pd

max_val = 25
a = range(1, 10)
s = pd.Series(a).cumsum()
s.loc[s > max_val] = np.nan
>>> s.ffill().astype(int).tolist()
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 21, 21, 21]
```